# Mongoose model - Clarification required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the below code snippet,all the fields are required in a post action and required attribute in schema definition is marked as true.After post,i need to update the doctors who perform a particular operation and for that i have created a put action.I don't have to insert procedureid in put action as its already there in db.Since required attribute is marked as mandatory ,do i need to pass the value of procedureid from client always?

If yes then is to possible to create a schema in such way that all fields are mandatory in post action and optional in put action?

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');   

 var hospitalDoctorSchema = new Schema({


    Treatment: {
                procedureid: { type: Number,required: true, unique: true,default: 0 },               

                doctor: {
                    doctorId: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true, default: 0 },

                },
    },
    updated_at: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) just modify the field that needs to be changed. You don't need to update all fields.

```
Doctor.findOneAndUpdate({_id: "59861d89be237e5c1e223cfc"}, {"$set": {"Treatment.doctor.doctorId": 747}}, {"new": true}, function(err, doctor){
    //doctor is the modified object
});
```